# domain name from URL in Php

Tags: php

i want to extract only domain name from given URL for any kind of TLD's . TLD can have any number in character or my be two in size

```
  <?php $domain_name = 'http://www.subdomain.domain.co.in' ;
        $ParsedURL = parse_url($domain_name);
        $domain_name = preg_replace("/^([a-zA-Z0-9].*\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,})$/", '$2', $ParsedURL['host']); 
        $domain_name = current(explode('.', $domain_name));
        print_r($domain_name);
```

so above solution is satisfying only limited URLs ,it fails when  TDL's are three or more in characters e.g org.in ,
Again i am getting different results when there is no subdomain in url .
Kindly help me out as i only want "domain" from Given URL

Comment: Don't think there's an easy way to do this without some constants. For example, is the domain name always going to have the http://www on it? Is there always going to be a sub-domain? Is there ever going to be an https? This is a fun problem, but I don't think there's going to be a simple solution.

Comment: what is the exact goal of replacing the domain name with $2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `/^\.{1}.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})?$/` the only thing would be to strip the first '.' from the matched string: `<?php substr($domain_name, 1);?>`

Comment: Thanks, its working fine in all TLD but fails when there is subdomain in url